# How to DRY up Tailwind CSS styles in React/Next.js components?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I've been using Tailwind CSS in my React/Next.js project and have noticed that my code has become less maintainable compared to when I used traditional CSS or styled-components. In the past, I could easily centralize style changes, but now, I find myself repeating classes for similar styling, like this:

```html
<div>
  <p className='text-[16px] text-red-700'>one</p>
  <p className='text-[16px] text-red-700'>two</p>
  <p className='text-[16px] text-red-700'>two</p>
</div>
```

This approach leads to code duplication and makes it harder to update styles consistently. What are the best practices for using Tailwind CSS in React/Next.js to maintain a single source of truth for styling, similar to how I used to do it with traditional CSS or styled-components?

I want to make my code cleaner and more maintainable while leveraging the power of Tailwind CSS. Any advice or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand the feeling.

I see have 2 simple solutions:

1. As you use React, if they are repeating elements in your code, with the same classes all the time. Create a component, in that case, it could be something like const Paragraph = (text) => {text}

Or,

2. Using Tailwind @apply. If you like creating your own CSS classes, this will feel more natural to you.

In your CSS file:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
   .p-custom {
     @apply text-[16px] text-red-700;
   }
}
```

Check this
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles#extracting-classes-with-apply

And this
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#layer

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Tailwind can be made DRY with `class-variance-authority (cva)`. More about cva [here](https://cva.style/docs).
`cva` lets you create different variants of a component according to your use case. For example:

```
import {cva} from "class-variance-authority"

const para = cva(
    ["flex items-center"],
    {
      variants: {
        variant: {
          default: " text-gray-700 ",
          error: " text-red-700 ",
          success: " text-green-700 ",
        },
        size: {
          default: " text-[12px] ",
          md: " text-[14px] ",
          lg: " text-[16px] ",
        },
     },
     defaultVariants: {
       variant: "default",
       size: "default",
     },
);


...


para()
// "flex items-center text-gray-700 text-[12px]"

para({variant: "error", size: "md"});
// "flex items-center text-red-700 text-[14px]"
```

You can add other variants like border, shadow, etc. according to your use case. Also look for [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx) and [tailwind-merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tailwind-merge) in combination with cva for further drying up your components with tailwind CSS and React/Next js.

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout the official page of `Tailwindcss` [LINK](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles)

OR

Try This:

You can use `.map()` function to iterate the the values.

```
const classes = "text-[16px] text-red-700";

const arr = ["one", "two", "three"];
<div>
{
arr.map(text=> (
<p className={classes} key={text} >{text}</p>
 ))
}
</div>
```